# Dynamic array of objects of parent class to hold child objects

Tags: c++, object-slicing

I have a `Mammal` parent class.
`Dog`, `Cat`, `Lion` are the sub-classes.

I am using vectors to hold all the sub-classes as `Mammal` object as such

```
vector<Mammal> v;
```

And using this line to append new objects to the vector.

```
v.push_back(new Dog(Name, Blue, Owner));
```

Apparently it doesn't work. `Error no instance of overload function` is thrown to me during compile. I am new to C++ so I am not sure what is the correct way to dynamically create an array of parent class to hold all the child object

Comment: First of all you should read about [*object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). Second of all, using `new` results in a *pointer*, and you have a vector of object and not a vector of pointers. Thirdly, when posting questions about build errors, please include the complete and unedited error output in the question.

Comment: Same as in your previous question: polymorphism **only** with pointers or references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

buchipper already gave you good advice. When you want to manage the lifetime of your pets correctly, consider to use `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>` instead of raw pointers:

```
// the vector owns the pets and kills them, when they are removed
// from the vector
vector<std::unique_ptr<Mamal> > v1

// the vector has shared ownership of the pets. It only kills them,
// when noone else needs them any more
vector<std::shared_ptr<Mamal> > v2

// the vector has no ownership of the pets. It never kills them.
vector<Mamal*> v3
```

In the last case, someone else has to take care of the pets death, or they'l hang around in your memory as zombies. You don't want to to that to your pets, do you?

**Update**
Oh, i forgot to mention, that you should prefer `make_shared()` and `make_unique()` over new, or use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`

```
v1.emplace_back(new Dog{Name, Blue, Owner});
v1.push_back(make_unique<Dog>(Name, Blue, Owner))

v2.emplace_back(new Dog{Name, Blue, Owner});
v2.push_back(make_shared<Dog>(Name, Blue, Owner))
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, you have a vector of Mammal objects and not pointers or references.

Try -

```
vector <Mammal *> v;
v.push_back(new Dog(Name, Blue, Owner));
```